# Magento registration date of birth in one field

Tags: date, register

I want that in my customer regitration form date of birth field to be in one field. Now it's in 3  fields. 
So I have

```
<div class="input-box customer-dob">
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('dob') ?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('dob') ?>"
           class="input-text validation-custom required-entry"/>
</div>
```

But validation don't working. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, instead of validate-custom provide validate-date as the class for the input field.

The validation script for this can be found in js/prototype/validation.js line 503

```
'validate-date', 'Please enter a valid date.', function(v) {
                var test = new Date(v);
                return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || !isNaN(test);
            }],
```

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question!

**You don't need jQuery** for this. You can do this with the built-in Magento form validator. First the javascript to set up the form for validation must be placed in your form template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myForm= new VarienForm('[your form id]', true);
</script>
```

Now prepare your form **fields** by adding the appropriate css classes.

**Cannot have number greater than 9.99**

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry validate-digits-range digits-range-0-9.99"/>
```

**No spaces in the fields**

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry validate-alphanum"/>
```

That's it! For the more specific use cases you'll have to add custom validation rules:

**Only number fields need to have .00 to validate 1 to 1.00**

```
Validation.add('validate-float','Input must be in the form of 0.00',function(v){
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || (!/\./.test(v));
});
```

Which then is validated with the following:

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry validate-float"/>
```

**Letters need to be uppercase**

This one is similar, the regex must test for a range of uppercase:

```
Validation.add('validate-uppercase','Input must be in uppercase',function(v){
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || (!/^[A-Z]+$/.test(v));
});
```

And used like:

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry validate-uppercase"/>
```

Please navigate this link hope it will help you:

```
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-frontend/magento-form-field-ajax-validation/
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is super simple – crack open your

> /js/varien/js.js

file and change this:

```
var error = false, day = parseInt(this.day.value) || 0, month = parseInt(this.month.value) || 0, year = parseInt(this.year.value) || 0;
```

which is on about `line 437`, to this:

```
var error = false, day = parseInt(this.day.value, 10) || 0, month = parseInt(this.month.value, 10) || 0, year = parseInt(this.year.value, 10) || 0;
```

and that’s it!

Answer (score 1):

What validate-date doesn't do is that it also accepts futuristic date.

I have created a class validation (using only Prototype) have a look , enjoy coding

```
<input type="hidden" name="dob" class="validate-dob" id="dob" current-date="<?php echo date('m/d/Y')?>"/>


Validation.add('validate-dob','Please enter a valid birthday',function(value,el){`enter preformatted text here`
                        if(value != ''){
                          var pattern =/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
                          var month = value.substring(0,2);
                          var day = value.substring(3,5);
                          var year = value.substring(6,10);
                          var current_date = el.readAttribute('current-date');
                          var current_month = current_date.substring(0,2);
                          var current_day = current_date.substring(3,5);
                          var current_year = current_date.substring(6,10);
                          var dob = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
                          var current_date = new Date(current_year, current_month - 1, current_day);
                          if(!pattern.test(value) || (current_date <= dob)){
                              return false;
                          }
                        }
                        return true;
                     });
```